# Forelse is not working properly in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-blade

My laravel version is 5.4.36. I want to use `forelse` to show message when the condition is not meet.

```
@forelse ($items as $item)
   <p>
     @if ($item->quantity<$item->minimum_no)
        <span class="label label-danger">Item {{$item->name}} need to be ordered now ! </span>
     @elseif($item->quantity<($item->minimum_no+10))
        <span class="label label-warning">Item {{$item->name}} is low !</span>
     @endif
   </p>
@empty
   <p>No message</p>
@endforelse
```

But, it only show the message when the condition is meet. When it is `@empty`, it does not show anything.

Comment: are you sure the `$items` collection is empty? maybe it may not be empty and it is the conditions of the `@if` and `@elseif` that are not met

Comment: do `dd($items);` and update the question with $items result when `empty`

Comment: I though it will go to `empty` when the if-else condition is not meet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@forelse` acts exactly like `@foreach` with one diff which is `@empty` command that will works if your array was empty
in the following example if `$users` was empty then `no users` will be place:

```
@forelse ($users as $user)
    <li>{{ $user->name }}</li>
@empty
    <p>No users</p>
@endforelse
```

in your code if `$item` is empty then `<p>No message</p>` will be placed and if it has one or more item then `if..else...` will works

**UPDATE depend on your condition**
if your condition is about item but not items so you need additional variable for checking it at end or something like it:

```
<?php $elseMsg='<p>No message</p>';?>
@foreach ($items as $item)
   <p>
     @if ($item->quantity<$item->minimum_no)
        <?php $elseMsg='';?>
        <span class="label label-danger">Item {{$item->name}} need to be ordered now ! </span>
     @elseif($item->quantity<($item->minimum_no+10))
        <?php $elseMsg='';?>
        <span class="label label-warning">Item {{$item->name}} is low !</span>
     @endif
   </p>
@endforelse
{{$elseMsg}}
```

Comment: How should I change it if I want to display the message when the if-else condition is not meet?

Comment: there are two case: do you want display `no message` per each item whenever `if-else` condition not meet or do you want `no message` once when non of items meet the condition?

Comment: no message once when non of items meet the condition.

Comment: so you have to check it separately. check my update